# How to repeat an if else if else loop according to my preference?

Tags: python

This is what I tried and , basically what I was trying to do was that, if a user enters other than 1,2,3,4,6 then it will go back to a=int(input.....)). But for me it keeps giving output as None.

```
def hi():
    while True:
        try:
            a=int(input("enter the denominator of Pi radian\n"
                "(choose from 1,2,3,4,6)\n"
                "Enter here:"))
            if a <=0 or a>=7 and a!=5:
                print("Enter the given digits")                     
            else:
                return a                       
        except Exception:
            print("enter a valid type")
ant=hi()

print(ant)
```

Comment: It returns the number for me

Comment: It returns a number as well. You have a mistake in the condition however. It should be `or a!=5` instead of `and a!=5`

Answer (score 0):

You have applied a wrong condition here:

```
if a <=0 or a>=7 and a!=5:
```

You're checking `a!=5` as a wrong input, when it should be `a==5`. Also apply `or` instead of `and`. Change it to:

```
if a <=0 or a>=7 or a==5:
```

Comment: How is that related to None being returned

Comment: I ain't getting any None with this code. I was getting wrong output and fixed the issue.